# Math.Tan does not work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, math

I am currently writing a calculation program for the Windows Phone. One of the calculations if to find the tangent of a number the user enters times another number the user enters.

The problem is when I typed in 1*tan(45) (which is 1) it returns 1.6.... I ran this through the debugger a couple of times. I can see 45 going into Math.Tan, and the output is 1.6.

Please help me identify the cause of this problem. Code below.

```
double result;
double multiplying = Convert.ToDouble(txtMultTan.Text);
double tangent = Convert.ToDouble(txtTan.Text);
result = multiplying * (Math.Tan(tangent));
txtResult.Text = "Answer= " + result;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure, if you read the documentation, you'll discover that the trig functions expect the input to be in radians. To convert from degrees to radians, multiply by `pi/180.0`, using whatever pre-defined constant of `pi` your math library offers.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is that the argument to `Math.Tan` must be in radians, and you seem to be giving it a value in degrees.  Multiply the value by pi/180 and you should get the expected result.

See the Wikipedia article on [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) for more information.

Comment: Got it upside down... say pi/180 or s/multiply/divide.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `Math.Tan` is expected to be in radians. Multiple by `Math.PI/180.0`. For example:

```
    const double DTR = Math.PI / 180.0;
    double angle = 45;
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Tan(angle * DTR)); // Prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in radians.

This is the case in "normal" .NET too - try it.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Tan(45));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when I run the Tan(45) on google the result is actually 1.6.  [Link](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=tan%2845%29&pbx=1&oq=tan%2845%29&aq=f&aqi=h1g4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1201l4435l0l5231l7l7l0l0l0l1l1162l2907l2-3.2.1.7-1l7l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=3a401dd6506c160d&biw=1280&bih=696)

Answer (score 0):

So hard to find !

To accomplish basic [triangle math](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-angle-right-triangle.html) in JavaScript, use ..

```
Math.atan(opposite/adjacent) * 180/Math.PI
```